# A manager wanted to use a project task list, but wanted a running log of the comments entered as the task is being worked

Tags: 2010, list, task-list

The project task list allows a gantt view and can be used for status updates.
Once the task is assigned, the assignee needs to provide regular status updates and update the task.  With a regular comments field there is no time stamp and the user must just add comments to the task and remember not to remove old comments.

Comment: I actually solved this issue by creating two fields and a workflow in SharePoint designer.

I added one field for Current Comments, and another field for Comment History.  
The Comment History was created with "Add to all content types" unchecked.

Then I created a list workflow with two steps that runs if Current Comments is not blank
1> Set Comments History equal to Comments History plus Current Comments.  I also insert Modified (date) and Modified By (display name) 

2> Set Current Comments to blank

The workflow runs on create or edit.

Comment: Mark, you should add that as an answer and accept it if that was what fixed your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved this issue by creating two fields and a workflow in SharePoint designer.

I added one field for Current Comments, and another field for Comment History.
The Comment History was created with "Add to all content types" unchecked.

Then I created a list workflow with two steps that runs if Current Comments is not blank
1> Set Comments History equal to Comments History plus Current Comments.  I also insert Modified (date) and Modified By (display name)

2> Set Current Comments to blank

The workflow runs on create or edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "comments" field - its built in to sharepoint and doesnt require workflows but is allowed to be append only so you cannot overwrite previous posters comments: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231529/comments-field-in-sharepoint-issue-tracking-list